# crontab need user to login once before it runs the script

Tags: linux, cron, centos, gnu-screen

I'm trying to schedule a game server restart and vps restart at a time. I made 3 cron entries (screen terminate, vps reboot, game server start)

crontab entry for root user

```
30 6 * * * /sbin/reboot
```

crontab entry for user1

```
29 6 * * * sleep 48; screen -S cs1 -X quit
31 6 * * * cd /home/user1/steamcmd/hlds; ./cs1.sh
```

cs1.sh

```
screen -dmS cs1 ./hlds_run -game cstrike -pingboost 2 +map de-dust +maxplayers 31 +port 27018
```

The problem is the `user1`'s second crontab entry is not working unless if I log in (via putty) after the reboot and before 6:31 AM. Can anyone experienced in this explain how to fix that?

Comment: You probably cannot run screen to create a new screen session, without having a tty connected to your shell. And the shell running your cron job will not have any tty connected.

Comment: What do you mean by that and how do I fix it?

Comment: When you log in, your terminal is the place where all programs can print their results. Your terminal is connected to all those programs. When a cron job is started, no terminal exists where the cron job could print its results, and therefore you can only run programs as a cron job which do not need a terminal. GNU screen apparently needs a terminal, so to fix it, you'd have to rewrite the code of GNU screen. So, most probably, this is something you cannot fix easily.

Comment: Ok, noted. Will I be able to achieve this using rc.local? If not what are the other ways to achieve this?

Comment: ADD: This says something about using sccreen on reboot "-d -m Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but doesn't attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts." Doesn't it mean we can use screen on reboot? Sorry if I sound like an ignorant person who can't accept some hard fact from people :p. I'm just trying to make it work.

Comment: screen -d -m sounds good, it might be your solution. The problem with the normal starting of screen is that screen starts a new session AND attaches your current terminal to this session. For this to work, it needs a terminal. If you can persuade screen to start a new session AND leave it detached right away, you could probably get away with no terminal available. You should try it.

Comment: That's the problem. cs1.sh is already using the parameter. Here's what cs1.sh contain: screen -dmS cs1 ./hlds_run -game cstrike -pingboost 2 +map de-dust +maxplayers 31 +port 27018

Answer (score 1):

I run a craftbukkit server that reboots every day at 0230. I found I couldn't call the startup script from crontab, but I could just run the screen command.

Here is my crontab entry for the server restart:

```
@reboot cd /home/mcadmin/craftbukkit && screen -dmS minecraft java -Xincgc -Xmx2048M -jar craftbukkit.jar
```